# jsfiddle alternative on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Is there a website similar to jsfiddle that can be accessed through a mobile. I want a website/tool that aids JavaScript/HTML/CSS development. Jsfiddle is very cumbersome when I use it on my phone (nexus 4).

Any suggestion on either online or offline tool is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: when i test my fiddles on mobile i mail myself the fiddles frame source OR you can click on the share button and send yourself/copy the share fullscreen result url

Comment: Try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhangns.runthecode

Comment: Try kodeWeave! - http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ashvin777.apps.jsitor, is web(JSitor.com) cum app solutions

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this one : http://jsbin.com/

Really simple and clean.

Answer (score -2):

try http://jsdo.it/

It is supposed to scale down appropriately for a mobile device.

Comment: pretty neat service, unfortunately the phone simulator allows hover...

Comment: Sadly, jsdo.it has ended on October 31, 2019.